# Cannot set background Image in IonCard Ionic4- React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-react

I am not able to set background image in my ioncard component . Here is my code

```
                 <IonRow>
                  {allCategories.categories.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                      <IonCol size="6" size-md="4" size-lg="3" key={index}>
                        <IonCard
                          onClick={() => getProducts(item)}
                          style={{
                            backgroundImage: `${item.image}`,
                            backgroundColor: "yellow",
                          }}
                        >
                          {/* <IonImg src={item.image} className="catImage" /> */}.  //this works fine but i want the image to be in background
                          <IonItem>
                            <IonLabel>{item.title}</IonLabel>
                          </IonItem>
                        </IonCard>
                      </IonCol>
                    );
                  })}
                </IonRow>
```

> backgroundColor:'yellow'

seems to work fine as this was just for checking, but i do not see anywhere the background image.
"IonImage" tag also works fine but i want the image to be in background...

Answer (score 0):

considering the image worked when it's used as a source I assume item.image is a url.

Can you wrap that value in `url()`

like so:

```js
 style={{
  backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})`,
  backgroundColor: "yellow",
 }}
```